# ASP Net - Forms Authentication with Active Directory Problem

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have an error...

The container specified in the connection string does not exist

Basically, I am using Active Directory authentication in ASP.NET.

I have set up my connection string.

I am still very new to AD.

I appritate any help
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably be better off specifying the root NC name in your connection.

LDAP://YourADServer/DC=cene,DC=edc,DC=CompName,DC=com

Unless there is a good reason why you don't want searches to be done domain-wide, I'd set it up like that.

You can try ldp.exe to connect to the AD server you have specified in the path and see if that works

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to be aware of is that Active Directory and Forms Authentication are not the same thing. You will use one or the other to Authenticate and Authorize.

Answer (score 1):

I think your LDAP string should be formatted thus:

`"LDAP://DCServer.BUSINESSPLUSPLUS.com/CN=Users,DC=BUSINESSPLUSPLUS,DC=com"`